# oracle forms javascript integration

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm trying to experiment with the new javascript integration features of oracle forms 11g.
My current configuration:

- Forms 11.1.2.2.0
- Weblogic 10.3.6.0
- JRE 1.7u55
- Windows 7 x64

I installed the demo at http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/11g/jsinteg/formsjsinteg/setup.htm

This is only working from FORMS to Javascript but not the other way. i.e Javascript to FORMS.
I thought all the additional Javascripts et al in it is making it difficult for me to know what's happening so I created a simpler html page with a textbox, a button and an anchor for onclick along with the applet in iFrame.

Again the code is working from FORMS to javascript but not the other way.

This line is not working:

```
window.frames['forms_iframe'].contentDocument.document.forms_applet.raiseEvent(event, payload);
```

UPDATE:
I changed it so the applet and all the testing code is placed in one html. and added some try catch code to my calls.
changed my call to:

```
function frmEvent (event, payload) {
    alert(event+", "+ payload);
    event = "PUSH";
    try {
        document.forms_applet.raiseEvent(event, payload);
    }
    catch(err) {
        var txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }

}
```

Now I get in IE

```
liveconnect call for applet id 1 is not allowed in this jvm instance
```

in chrome, it says:

```
Error calling method on NPObject
```

I think the whole problem is with this liveconnect changes to java runtime... wondering what else to do to solve this issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower the Java security setting from High (only authorized Java script can be run) to Medium (Prompt before unauthorized Java script), user will receive a prompt and then the worksheet can be opened just 
fine. It's due to higher security requirement with JRE 7u45

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/updated_security_baseline_7u45_impacts